# Get raw value of property attribute using Reflection

Tags: c#, .net-core, reflection

I need to mark some properties as passwords so that they could be automatically screened. I found a standard attribute for that:

```
[PasswordPropertyText]
public string ThePassword { get; set; }
```

Following method checks if the attribute is there:

```
private static bool _isPassword(PropertyInfo p)
{
    PasswordPropertyTextAttribute passProp = (PasswordPropertyTextAttribute)p.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(PasswordPropertyTextAttribute));
    return (passProp != null); // Additional condition should go here
}
```

Now I would like to have my own logic here:

- **[PasswordPropertyText]** should result in **true**.
- **[PasswordPropertyText(true)]** should result in **true**.
- **[PasswordPropertyText(false)]** should result in **false**.

but the default value of `PasswordPropertyTextAttribute.Password` is **false** when the argument is omitted.

Is there any way to get the raw attribute value?

Comment: You will need to create your own Attribute that conforms to your use case.  Since the param is passed in the contructor, and then used by the attribute class, it would be based on how that value is stored in the attribute class (as you stated, this value is assigned to an underlying field with a default value of false).  It should be simple enough to replace the attribute in question with your own version, perhaps with the default value of true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since attribute constructor information are stored as metadata as well you can get the required information by calling the `GetCustomAttributesData` method. Have a look at this simple example:

```
class Program
{
    [PasswordPropertyText]
    public string Password1 { get; set; }

    [PasswordPropertyText(true)]
    public string Password2 { get; set; }

    [PasswordPropertyText(false)]
    public string Password3 { get; set; }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var props = typeof(Program).GetProperties();
        foreach(var prop in props)
        {
            var attributeData = prop.GetCustomAttributesData().First(x => x.AttributeType == typeof(PasswordPropertyTextAttribute));
            Console.WriteLine($"{prop.Name}: {(attributeData.ConstructorArguments.Cast<CustomAttributeTypedArgument?>().FirstOrDefault()?.Value ?? true)}");
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Password1: True
Password2: True
Password3: False
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing cannot be done using reflection.

Reflection is not looking at the *code* as it was written: it is looking at the model that results from that code. Since the default constructor for `PasswordPropertyTextAttribute` passes a `false` value to another constructor, the model that it produces is indistinguishable from using `[PasswordPropertyText(false)]`.

If you want different behavior from the built-in attribute, I'd recommend creating your own attribute that has the behavior you're looking for instead.